# Error con variable de promesa (lateinit) en Kotlin con Android

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

Estoy observando un EditText con la ayuda de TextWatcher. Para esto ubico toda sintaxis en una clase aparte ya que estaré usando el mismo método en diferentes partes de la aplicación.

Implementando ViewModel, recibo el resultado en la vista por medio de una interfaz y cuando trato de mandarlo a la clase ViewModel me sale este error: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property viewModel has not been initialized.

Por lo que entiendo, es causado porque la variable que le prometí inicializar no la inicialicé.

Así es el proceso de comunicación:

1. Clase Fragment: Es la vista, por lo que aqui tendría que llegar el dato obtenido por TextWatcher.

   private const val KEY_USERNAME = "username_key"
   private const val KEY_PASSWORD = "password_key"

class LoginFragment : Fragment(), IData {

```
private lateinit var binding: FragmentLoginBinding

private lateinit var viewModel: LoginViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater, R.layout.fragment_login, container, false
    )
    Log.i("onCreateView", "called onCreateView")

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[LoginViewModel::class.java]

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        binding.inputUserName.editText?.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_USERNAME, ""))
        binding.inputPassword.editText?.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_PASSWORD, ""))
    }

    binding.inputUserName.editText?.addTextChangedListener(TextWatcherResource("username"))
    binding.inputPassword.editText?.addTextChangedListener(TextWatcherResource("password"))

    return binding.root
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

    outState.putString(KEY_USERNAME, binding.inputUserName.editText?.text.toString())
    outState.putString(KEY_PASSWORD, binding.inputPassword.editText?.text.toString())
}

override fun onValue(value: String) {
    viewModel.onSetCredentials(value)
}
```

}

2. Clase TextWatcherResource: Ejecuta las operaciones de TextWatcher para captar el texto mientras es digitado por el usuario.

class TextWatcherResource(reference: String) : TextWatcher {

private val login: IData = LoginFragment()
private val subReference = reference

```
override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
    Log.i("TextWatcherResource", "Called beforeTextChanged")
}

override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    Log.i("TextWatcherResource", "Called onTextChanged")
}

override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
    Log.i("TextWatcherResource", "Called afterTextChanged")

    val value = "$subReference-${s.toString()}"
    login.onValue(value)
}
```

}

3. Interface IData: Es el puente que uso para enviar el dato obtenido por el TextWatcher.

interface IData {
fun onValue(value: String)
}

Se puede ver que la variable viewModel si se inicializa y lo rectifico con el Log que imprimo cuando se incia la aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiar tu linea:

private lateinit var viewModel: LoginViewModel

por:

```
private var viewModel: LoginViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

y eliminas:

viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[LoginViewModel::class.java]

de tu onCreateView()